# Management of test cases and test runs for an application developed for multiple countries?

Tags: manual-testing, test-management, testcase

I am working on an application which is developed on multiple countries.
It has common features, and based on country, specific features, which are according to the countries.

We use QC for test management - test design and test execution.

My questions:

- How you created/managed the test cases in this case? Have the common test cases in one area and specific ones in countries folder or have tests multiplicated for each country?
- How you handle execution of manual test cases? You run on all countries  or run on one instance the common tests and specific ones on the required country?
  For automated tests I consider having test cases for each country, and run them  on each country all of them  (common + specific).

Answer (score 2):

I have sent you reference link for your problem solution.

1. How you created/managed the test cases in this case?

http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/hp-quality-center-tutorial-4/

2. How you handle execution of manual test cases?

http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/hp-quality-center-tutorial-5/

Comment: Hello, 10x for the answer. For me the problem is not how to use the tool, is how to handle the situation with multiple country situation.

Comment: Hello, Correct !! I will update you soon.. :)

Comment: Hi Jensi..Do you have any updates?

Comment: Still have no any update, If have then will inform you.